# UpdateOrCreate with model instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `PHP 7.1.33` and `Laravel Framework 5.8.36`.

I am getting receiving data from a database `row-by-row` and I am creating a model using `updateOrCreate()` like the following:

```
foreach ($arr as $v) {

    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = $v['name'];
    $product->url = $v['url'];
    $product->price = $v['price'];

    // save
    $matchThese = ['name' => $name, 'url' => $url];
    $product->updateOrCreate($matchThese);
}
```

However, nothing gets created.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateOrCreate` takes 2 parameters (`$attributes`, `$values`).

`$attributes` is an array containing key-value pairs which will basically be used for where clauses i.e. it will check the database for the attributes passed in this array.

`$values` is an array containing key-value pairs of what to update in the database.

If it can't find a row in the database matching the first array it will combine the values in the arrays to create a new row.

To achieve what you're after you can do:

```
Product::updateOrCreate(
    ['name' => $v['name'], 'url' => $v['url']],
    ['price' => $v['price']]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
Product::updateOrCreate(
    ['name' => $name, 'url' => $url],
    ['price' => v['price']],
)
```

First parameter is for search the register.
Second parameter set new values.

For more information, you can read [Eloquent: Getting Started - Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

Comment: You have the param order the wrong way round is your description, the first param is for searching and the second is for updating values. Also, you wouldn't want to add the price to the first array as it seems that might be the value that the OP wants to update (if the row exists).